# WinForms threading invoke handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

This code is running from other thread than the thread it was created on.
Thread gets create from the constructor of `StartScanning`

```
public StartScanning()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Thread _IMSS_THREAD = new Thread(_IMSS_START_SCANNING);
    _IMSS_THREAD.IsBackground = true;
    _IMSS_THREAD.Start();
}
```

Main form

```
StartScanning _IMSS_START_SCANNING = StartScanning._IMSS_CREATE_CONTROLE();
_IMSS_START_SCANNING._IMSS_ON_ALL_SCAN_COMPLETE += _IMSS_ON_SCAN_COMPLETE;
this._IMSS_MainPanel.Controls.Add(_IMSS_START_SCANNING);
```

On scan complete user control, this code is in main form:

```
ScanComplete _IMSS_ON_COMPLETE = new ScanComplete();

public void _IMSS_ON_SCAN_COMPLETE(ref List<BetterListViewGroup> _IMSS_LIST_OF_GROUP_TARGETS)
{
    List<BetterListViewGroup> IMSS_LIST_OF_GROUP_TARGETS = _IMSS_LIST_OF_GROUP_TARGETS;
    _IMSS_ON_COMPLETE._IMSS_AddRangeTargets(ref IMSS_LIST_OF_GROUP_TARGETS);
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            this._IMSS_MainPanel.Controls.Clear();
            this._IMSS_MainPanel.Controls.Add(_IMSS_ON_COMPLETE);
        }));
}
```

If you take a look on this code, it runs OK but it's supposed to throw
Cross-thread operation not valid, cause when we start the program this UserControl

```
ScanComplete _IMSS_ON_COMPLETE = new ScanComplete();
```

Get created on the main thread (it's global) and when we use

```
_IMSS_ON_COMPLETE._IMSS_AddRangeTargets(ref IMSS_LIST_OF_GROUP_TARGETS);
```

It adds a list of groups of `listview` to it, and it's out of the invoke section, but it's not throwing thread error, Why it's not throwing errors?

Comment: And most relevant: WinForms, WPF, other?

Comment: Windows forms application

Comment: Where are you creating those threads? i dont see any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in constructor of form:

```
public StartScanning()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartScanning.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
}
```

Remember that this is not proper way to do this but this will help you to solve your problem. Search for **Thread safe calling**.